# Problems with UIScrollView size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uiscrollview

I try at the moment to resize the UIScrollView dynamically like in Android with wrap_content as attribute.

The data comes over a SQL Query that i start in the `override func viewDidLoad()`

I tried the freeform size variant and the version with extension

```
extension UIScrollView {

    func resizeScrollViewContentSize() {
        var contentRect = CGRect.zero
        for view in self.subviews {
            contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
        }
        self.contentSize = contentRect.size
    }
}
```

But nothing helps. Has Someone an idea?

[image: UIScrollView did not show everything]

**EDIT:**

@Stephen J I didn't understand your answer, sorry :(

I have a subview, too but how I can say the Scrollview that equals his size? I tried it with CTRL + Drag the mouse on the Scrollview and the same in the other direction.

So it looks at my Storyboard

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: This has been asked before without SQL in the question. I dealt with this issue myself last year when making a calendar... basically you need your inner content view to be resized (which you have), but then you also have to add constraints, like width and height. I forget what else... I remember using a subview then adding a width and height constraint. Something makes no sense though, as in, you might have to hook constraints to the uiscrollview from your subview, instead of the content itself. It's messy, but you'll get it after trying different setups.

Comment: Just noticed you type "ziemlich schwer" in the sample image, haha. It is, since it took me about 2 hours, was embarrassing since I've done graphics so long, but constraints are not useful, at all. It's faster to write algebra frame logic than it is to deal with them... feel free to turn them off if they get too annoying

Answer (score 0):

The idea is OK, but...

Your extension is looping through the subviews of the Scroll view, but your Scroll view contains only **ONE** subview - your `ContentView`... and *that* view contains a bunch of subviews. (Actually, the Scroll view's subviews property *also* contains the scrollIndicator bars, but that doesn't really factor in here).

What you want to do is loop through the subviews of your `ContentView`, then change *its* size, and then set the `.contentSize` of the Scroll view based on the `ContentView`.

So...

```
    // init empty rect
    var contentRect = CGRect.zero

    // for each subview in the ** Content ** view - NOT in the Scroll view
    for view in theContentView.subviews {
        // union the view's rect with the "total" rect
        contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
    }

    // set the frame size of the Content view to the "total" rect size
    theContentView.frame.size = contentRect.size

    // increast the size of the "total" rect by the Content view's x,y offsets
    contentRect.size.width += theContentView.frame.origin.x
    contentRect.size.height += theContentView.frame.origin.y

    // NOW we can set the contentSize of the Scroll view
    theScrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
```

Personally, I've found using auto-layout and constraints to make working with Scroll views really, really easy - easier than this method, because you don't have to keep re-calculating. But, if this works for you, great :)

**Edit:** Here is a complete working example. It:

1. creates a ScrollView sized to the full view
2. adds a ContentView *without size*
3. adds 30 labels vertically with 16 pts spacing
4. then calculates and sets the size of the ContentView and the .contentSize of the Scroll view based on the ContentView's subviews

---

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  SWScrollNoAutoLayout
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 6/14/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 DonMag. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let theScrollView = UIScrollView()

        let theContentView = UIView()

        theScrollView.frame = self.view.bounds
        theScrollView.backgroundColor = .orange

        theContentView.backgroundColor = .yellow

        self.view.addSubview(theScrollView)

        theScrollView.addSubview(theContentView)

        var yOffset: CGFloat = 0.0

        for i in 1...30 {

            let lbl = UILabel()

            lbl.text = "Label: \(i)"
            lbl.backgroundColor = .cyan
            lbl.sizeToFit()
            lbl.frame.origin.y = yOffset

            theContentView.addSubview(lbl)

            yOffset += lbl.frame.size.height + 16

        }


        // init empty rect
        var contentRect = CGRect.zero

        // for each subview in the ** Content ** view - NOT in the Scroll view
        for view in theContentView.subviews {
            // union the view's rect with the "total" rect
            contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
        }

        // set the frame size of the Content view to the "total" rect size
        theContentView.frame.size = contentRect.size

        // increast the size of the "total" rect by the Content view's x,y offsets
        contentRect.size.width += theContentView.frame.origin.x
        contentRect.size.height += theContentView.frame.origin.y

        // NOW we can set the contentSize of the Scroll view
        theScrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size


    }

}
```

Comment: @DonMog thanks for the answer but it does not work

he is make a union of each subview but the height is the same as before :(

Comment: @SebastianR. -- Is the *content height* incorrect? Is it possible you have set the frame of the Scroll view so it extends below the main view frame?

Comment: @DonMog yep it looks like the above picture from me

No, i don't think so that the scrollview extends below the mainview

Comment: @SebastianR. is "ziemlich schwer..." label the bottom label in your ContentView? If so, what is the frame of that label... what is the frame of ContentView... what is the frame of the Scroll view.... and what is the Scroll view's .contentSize?

Comment: @DonMog nope there 2 other labels after "ziemlich schwer.." label
the frame of all labels an of the Map is the ContentView. The Frame of the ContentView is the ScrollView and the contentSize what appears in the extends function is 683.0, the real one is by 1000 in freeform

Comment: ok... *"the Frame of the ContentView is the ScrollView"* ... and your extension is showing 683.0 ... that tells me you are calculating the size of the ***ContentView*** but you need to calculate the size of the ***subviews*** of the ContentView.

Comment: I pass the ContentView to the extension and there he access each subview i also include a counter to check and it's 21 views what i do wrong

Comment: Set a debug breakpoint and step through the loop? Maybe... are you adding the subviews all at `0,0`, then calling `resizeScrollViewContentSize()`, and *then* changing the size/position of each subview?

Comment: Yep i set breakpoints and he is adding the size of each subview to the `contentRect`
i call the `resizeScrollViewContentSize()` after adding the data to the labels in the `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: @SebastianR. -- not sure what might be wrong... I've added a complete example to my answer. Try running that  and see if the sizing / scrolling works. Then see if you can tell what's different.